# Where can I get libGLU.so.1 on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, archlinux

I'm running arch linux and am making an attempt to run DaVinci Resolve. Initially startup said nothing, it just timed out and closed. Then I found a recommendation to run it with `/opt/resolve/bin/resolve` this got me an error saying 
`libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This has sent me on a wild goose chase trying to install libGLU.so.1 on my system. I heard somewhere it is part of mesa so I `sudo pacman -S mesa` and I've tried to find a AUR package that might have it but no luck. Even trying variations of `yay libGLU` and `yay libGLU-mesa`, no luck so far.

Additionally `find / -name 'libLGU*'` returned nothing even when ran with sudo, meaning it isn't already on my system in the wrong directory.

This might unfortunately be an instance where I download the file and place it where it needs to go but that's probably not in the best interest of the long term longevity of my system.

I'm probably fairly novice when compared to most others on linux but I think I've gotten a lot of the basics down. Would love any insight you may have on this issue!

Comment: I have it owned by `glu 9.0.1-2` Note `libGLU.so.1` is simply a symlink to `libGLU.so.1.3.1`

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin ! Finally a new error lol xD

Comment: Happens. I'm sill waiting or Oracle to fix Arch guests so they don't Kernel Panic with kernel > 5.9 (which Arch is running 5.11 now...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While an outdated forum post said that `/usr/lib/libGLU.so.1` is owned by the `mesa` package, it is now currently owned by `glu`.

`pacman -S glu` ought to give you your needed library.

Comment: I saw that too but after reinstalling mesa just to be sure I had it, still no change. I even restarted real quick just to make sure the changes took.

Comment: @Math0898 that's interesting. Did you run the command shown to see who the package is owned by? Also, if you `ldd` your program binary, you get the full path of where the program expects libGLU.so.1 to be in.

Comment: For Archlinux, it is definitely provided by the `glu` package. It is not in the current `mesa`. I have all updates though about 30 min. ago.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for clearing up the issue. I updated the answer appropriately

Comment: No worries -- stuff gets moved around over time (and packages split, etc...).. No dings.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, you can reverse search filename->package using `pkgfile`, which works even if you don't have the respective files/packages locally.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pkgfile

```sh
$ sudo pkgfile --update
$ pkgfile libGLU.so.1
extra/glu
```

Alternatively there's the built-in `pacman -F`, but it's generally slower than `pkgfile`.